# jQuery Mobile 1.1.0 RC1 Modifying HREF for AJAX Posts in iOS Safari

Tags: jquery, iphone, ios, mobile, jquery-mobile

Disclaimer: I am using jQuery Mobile 1.1.0 RC1 which is not a stable release yet. I have a link that needs to post an AJAX request and return a JSON response but when the link is clicked it seems that jQuery Mobile changes the HREF to a hash (#) in iOS Safari on the iPhone. It does not do this when testing in browsers with iPhone User Agents. Here is my basic HTML and JS to show what I have:

```
<a href="/link/to/ajaxpost/">Send Ajax Request</a>
```

and the JS

```
$('#tab a').on('click', function(e){
        var $this = $(this);
        var jsonUrl = $this.attr("href");
        alert(jsonUrl);

        $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: jsonUrl,
            success: function(data) {
                $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
                alert(data);
            }
        });
        return false; 
});
```

The value for "jsonUrl" becomes "#" (instead of the url to my ajax request) and then the value of the data variable returns the entire page and not the JSON feed that I want. The weird thing is that this only happens in iOS Safari on the iPhone. It works fine and the JSON feed comes back when I try the jQuery Mobile site with a different user agent in OSX Safari or Firefox.

I've tried adding rel="external" and data-type="ajax" to the link and it doesn't fix it. I'm also using jQuery Mobile 1.1.0 RC1, but I'm not sure if that is the issue or if I'm just not using jQuery Mobile correctly. I also don't have any other jQuery Mobile specific JS in my code, so maybe I'm missing something that will fix this. Appreciate the help.

Comment: I know I COULD put the URL for the link in a data attribute and then call that with jQuery, but there has to be a better way to do it. I don't want to have to put in data attributes for every link.

Comment: Also tried $(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){ $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false; }); but no luck

Comment: I couldn't replicate your problem.  http://jsfiddle.net/sDh4k/3/

Comment: @r0m4n thanks! You just reminded me to try different versions of jQuery Mobile since I was using RC1.1. I found that the error only occurs in the latest build and not in the existing stable release:

This example uses jQuery Mobile 1.0.1 and works in iOS Safari (your jsfiddle):
http://jsfiddle.net/sDh4k/3/

This uses 1.1.0 RC1 and replaces the HREF with a hash in iOS Safari, which breaks the AJAX post:
http://jsfiddle.net/sDh4k/6/

Comment: Not sure what is happening, but maybe jQuery Mobile is ignoring rel="external" or any other method to leave links alone? If I change the event to vclick (http://jsfiddle.net/sDh4k/8/) it works, so is the solution to use that as the click event or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: hmmmm hard to say. jsfiddle revision 6 is working in my browser as well (I am testing with Firefox)

Comment: So this question was only about iOS Safari, it works in all my browsers with the UA changed to iPhone

Comment: I'm seeing the same bad behavior in released 1.1, w/ a similar problem.  Seems like on iOS Safari the attr('href') returns '#' for any link in a listview.  http://jsfiddle.net/LP66e/3/

Comment: @Keith See my answer below - you're intuition to use a data attribute seems bang on to me...but you don't have to do it yourself. jQuery Mobile does it for you!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
$this.attr('href')
```

Use this:

```
$this.data('href') || $this.attr('href')
```

jQuery Mobile 1.1.0RC1 and on (including released 1.1.0) will set the href to any link to `#` when it is clicked, and store the href in a `data-href` attribute, until it's done doing it's thing, then put it back. *It only does this on iOS Mobile Safari.*

I've blogged a bit more about this, with links to related github issues discussions and some info on applying this with Ruby on Rails jQuery UJS here:

http://scottwb.com/blog/2012/06/29/jquery-mobile-breaks-your-hrefs-on-ios-mobile-safari/