# Can't alert href val?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xcode, jquery-mobile, href

The following code gives me an alert with nothing but a # symbol inside it. Why?

EDIT: I should note that the code is inside a jQuery .click event...if I place it outside of that, it works properly. Here is the fuller code:

```
 $('#continue').click(function(){
                                 var _href = $("#continue").attr("href");
                                 alert(_href);                                
            });


<a href="selectRadius.html" data-icon="arrow-r" id="continue" style="float:right;" data-role="button" data-inline="true">Continue</a>
```

EDIT2: This all works fine in jsfiddle. But in the xcode iphone simulator I just get #.

Comment: Working here: http://jsfiddle.net/CFpeU/3/ hope you ar including <script> tag like this: http://jsfiddle.net/CFpeU/5/

Comment: Are you using jQuery Mobile et jQuery UI, by any chance ?

Comment: Mobile. And yes, yes, I'm using my script tag, lol. Your fiddle is identical to my code...confusing. This is being tested inside the xcode iPhone simulator, and giving different results. Granted, jQuery Mobile is involved, so...

Comment: When I use the *exact same code* in an inline script rather than in head, it alerts the right value. Bizarre.

Comment: You probably have an other piece of code interfering with that element. The code you have provided simply doesn't reproduce the problem. Here's a jsFiddle of it : http://jsfiddle.net/EvBmC/2/

Comment: I copied my page's entire code over to jsfiddle and it worked properly there. So now I'm at a loss for where to take this question.

Comment: I seem to remember reading something about how the iPhone browser raises 'tap' events rather than 'click' events, but bugger if I can't find the bookmark... :p

Comment: Nah click works fine. Good try though.

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you tried the jsfiddle in an actual iPhone?

Comment: Probably related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9881219/jquery-mobile-1-1-0-rc1-modifying-href-for-ajax-posts-in-ios-safari

Comment: That shouldn't change anything. The jsfiddle environment remains unchanged. It has to be run in the actual browser. If that's what you meant, then no, I don't have a device set up right now.

Comment: jsfiddles do run in the browser... although jQuery Mobile isn't an option at the moment.  But it looks like @HoLyVieR might have found the source of your problem.

Comment: That topic concludes that it's a bug in the jQuery Mobile code, lol.

Comment: Does the code work on FFX? my example works on FFX, Chrome and Android 2.3.

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault.html 

Some bugs do slip in products such as JQM or others, but something as basic as this should be ok. Plus, it would just render the product unusable.

Comment: JQM has a long issues board with an active team recognizing and repairing bugs...it's a relatively new framework. There are glitches here and there. Although I respect your point.

Comment: Problem found. See my answer. I'm going to use a form instead of an anchor as a work-around for the time being.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging by only the code you typed, probably the code runs too early. Try wrapping the JS in

```
$(function() {
    // your code here
});
```

Or

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    // your code here
});
```

**Update:**

Well, since it's an iPhone simulator, it changes things. Remember, nobody can help you unless you give all the details of the problem, no matter how much experience they have.

Did you try the touchstart / touchend / tap events instead of click? As far as I know, Apple has been having problems with the click events. Also, click events on mobile devices will have a slower response (a delay of approx 300ms if I remember well) so you're better just using touch specific events.

What are you building? Is it a mobile web app or? Will it run in a standard mobile browser or something like PhoneGap etc?

**Update2:**

Ok. It works as long as the code is not called on Click. This eliminates the possibility of another piece of code replacing your "href" with another value because that code would have to be inside your `$('#continue').click(function(){ });` block.

The click event is simulated on a touch phone, that's why the touch events are faster (they are native) and less likely to cause problems. You should also make sure that you return false there and not follow the link, that might be what's replacing your "href".

Comment: I doubt it.  It can't find `#continue` because it's not there yet.  You need to not call `click` until the DOM has loaded, hence the use of `$(document).ready`...

Comment: To be honest, it's already in that. This is part of a larger script which is all inside $(function(){code here});

Comment: @MarkReed Assuming his code alert "#", it found the element otherwise it would have alert "undefined". The problem is finding out what replaced the href of the element to "#".

Comment: Oh, d'oh, he's getting the alert popup, just with the wrong value.  Sorry.

Comment: I'm sorry for the incomplete information. My mistake. But as far as *I* know, .click works fine. I've been using it extensively without any errors.

Comment: I put in a final update. If you don't try it, I can't help you, can't replicate, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#continue').click(function(e) {
        var _href = $(this).attr('href');
        alert(_href);

        e.preventDefault();
        return(false);
        /*
           the return is legacy code, used by some
           browsers to detect if current event handler
           is braking default behaviour

           the e.preventDefault() function is the jQuery
           way to do it
        */
    });
});
</script>

<a href="selectRadius.html" data-icon="arrow-r" id="continue" style="float:right;" data-role="button" data-inline="true">Continue</a>
```

Without this line the link is followed and a refresh occurs killing the current script.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not solve the problem. I still get a hash sign.

Comment: As others have said, the href of the continue button might have been replaced to **#** by some piece of code in another part of the application. Search your entire project for #continue and see if it's been mentioned anywhere else.

Comment: Problem found. See my answer. I'm going to use a form instead of an anchor as a work-around for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/3777